# How to extend C drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

[image: Here is my partitions]

I want to extend the volume in the C drive,but the arrangement is like in `Disk 0` and `Disk 1` which is why I can't add space from E, D or F.

But I want to add some **volume** from the partitions E, D or F and add it to **C**.

How can I do that ?

Is it even possible ?

I've search for some free tools like **Mini Tool Partition Wizard** but I can't achieve with that too.

Please help, as I'm trying to figure it out from last 2 days.

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: It IS possible, but only with dynamic disks or storage spaces. But it does NOT appear it is an option for you nor would it be recommended in this use case probably. It would require using a form of RAID, making both drives part of one volume.

Comment: How can I do that ? making  both drives part of one volume ? @Appleoddity

Comment: And I don't know why it is in form of Disk0 and Disk1 ?

Comment: I just gave you 3 keywords: “storage spaces”, “dynamic disks”, and “RAID.” Please do some research. It’s too complicated to tell you what works in your situation or exactly what to do. I can tell you it will definitely require wiping both drives and reinstalling your OS or backing up and restoring images.

Comment: Then no offense, you are heading down a road that is likely to end in despair. It shows as disk 0 and disk 1 because you have two different disks in your computer! One is probably a 32Gb flash drive and then you have a 500GB HDD.

Comment: okay, so you are saying that it is tough to achieve this,because I've no idea !

Comment: Can I change the volume of C, at the time of installing new OS ?

Comment: What is the actual size of your Disk 0?

Comment: @mehmoodkhan - You can install Windows on any disk you want.  You would want to pick the unallocated space if you use Disk 1

Comment: Its 29.8GB ,  you can see in the image @Ramhound

Comment: @mehmoodkhan - They don't sell 29.8 GB drives.  The closest size would be 32 GB, is that size, of your SSD?

Comment: You need to install Windows on Disk 1, replacing the current Disk 0. But are you able to backup the Disk 1 which may be destroyed in the process? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: well, as far as backup is concerned , I've that, but do I need to set some space in Disk1 for new OS (unallocatted space), and then install new OS there ? @harrymc

Answer (score 0):

You have more than enough unallocated space on disk 1 for installing Windows.

I suggest to disconnect Disk 0 while you are installing Windows from bootable media,
connect Disk 1 instead (use the connector of disk 0), then install.
Be careful to indicate to the installation the unallocated space as the
location for the installation.

The current small disk can be connected in place of the current disk 1,
although it is too small to be very useful.

Take good backups and plan to the case where some error will destroy useful
data on disk 1 during the installation. Better be ready than sorry.